# Google Cloud Data flow : CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.withScan(), how to pass dynamic filter values?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

SourceLocation is prefix for my Bigtable, which is fetched from application.properties. Is there a way to fetch it dynamically while running the data flow template?

**My Pipeline:**

```
pipeline.apply("ReadTable", Read.from(CloudBigtableIO.read(configSetUp(options))))
```

**CloudBigtableScanConfiguration**

```
private static CloudBigtableScanConfiguration configSetUp(LocationSetupOptions options) {
    ValueProvider<Integer>  pageFilter = options.getPageFilter();
    Scan scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(options.getSourceLocation().get()));

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList();
    PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(options.getSourceLocation().get()));
    filterList.addFilter(new PageFilter(Long.valueOf(pageFilter.get())));
    filterList.addFilter(prefixFilter);
    scan.setFilter(filterList);

    return new CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
        .withProjectId(options.getProjectId())
        .withInstanceId(options.getInstanceId())
        .withTableId(options.getTableId())
        .withScan(scan)
        .build();}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two clients for Bigtable `CloudBigtableIO` and `BigtableIO`.  The CloudBigtableIO parameters are not updated to be modified by templates via a ValueProvider but BigtableIO is compatible with ValueProviders.

In your particular case if you are looking for `ValueProvider` to be used along with template then I would recommend that you move to using `BigtableIO`. A sample can be found here [AvroToBigtable](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/AvroToBigtable.java).

#### UPDATE

The [@Default.InstanceFactory](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/Default.InstanceFactory.html) can be used to specify a user-provided factory method to generate default values for a parameter. With this, you could read the default value from a resource file inside of your DefaultValueFactory implementation.

As an example, you can check how [WindowedWordCount](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d6e6ea9c72bbccd96c36ddcb60a513a0b420563a/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WindowedWordCount.java#L156) defines DefaultToCurrentSystemTime to annotate the minTimestampMillis parameter:

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am able to use ValueProvider with CloudBigtableIO. While constructing the template, BigTable prefix is fetched from application properties . Is there a way to pass runtime prefix while executing the template? Appreciate your response

Comment: I have updated the answer. If this was helpful please do accept the answer.

Comment: I have a similar implementation to get the default values from application properties. Our pipeline, queries Bigtable with the certain input, process the results  and inserts to another table. I'm facing issue in passing dynamic inputs for big-table query , while executing the pipeline template. Appreciate your response